# Azure Cognitive Search on private endpoints - implement Function for built-in skills

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-services

It says here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services?tabs=portal%2Cportal-remove#how-the-key-is-used
"*If disabling public networks is a requirement, you can configure a Custom Web API skill implemented with an Azure Function that supports private endpoints and add the Azure AI services resource to the same VNET. In this way, you can call Azure AI services resource directly from the custom skill using private endpoints.*"

Disabling public networks is my requirement, but this does not say what that function should do!
I want to use built-in skills....

I've written a custom skill in a function, but how would I implement a function which is a proxy to the built-in skills? There appear to be classes for them in Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models, but I can't find any examples. THANKS!

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214406/azure-search-using-rest-c-sharp) and msdoc [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-attach-cognitive-services?tabs=cogkey-csharp%2Ccogkey-rest-remove#how-the-key-is-used)

Comment: rather than using the `Microsoft.Azure.Search` deprecation package use `Azure.Search`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it working....

To allow you to use the Cognitive Search skills **within** private endpoints, you have to write a Function which implements a custom skill and serves as a proxy to the skills. Slightly annoying that this isn't built-in, but the code isn't that complex.

It's a good idea for the function API to mirror the skill's API.

For example, the PII Detection skill https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-pii-detection:

The input class is:

```
    internal class PIIInputRecord  
    {
        public string RecordId { get; set; }
        public class SkillInputs
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string language { get; set; }
        }
        public SkillInputs Data { get; set; }
    }
```

The output class is:

```
    internal sealed class PIIOutputRecord
    {
        internal class PIIOutputData
        {
            public string RedactedText { get; set; }
            public PiiEntityCollection PIIEntities { get; set; }
        }
        public string RecordId { get; set; }
        public PIIOutputData Data { get; set; } = new PIIOutputData();
        public List<OutputRecordMessage> Errors { get; set; }
        public List<OutputRecordMessage> Warnings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the function implementation is:

```
        [FunctionName("PIIDetectionSkill")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            var response = new WebApiResponse
            {
                Values = new List<PIIOutputRecord>()
            };

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebApiRequest>(requestBody);

            // 1. Validate the request
            // 2. Create an instance of TextAnalyticsClient using your API + Key
            // 3. Then.... 
            // Calculate the response for each value.
            foreach (var record in data.Values)
            {
                if (record == null || record.RecordId == null) continue;
                PIIOutputRecord responseRecord = new PIIOutputRecord
                {
                    RecordId = record.RecordId
                };
                try
                {
                    PiiEntityCollection entities = (await client.RecognizePiiEntitiesAsync(record.Data.text)).Value;
                    responseRecord.Data.RedactedText = entities.RedactedText;
                    responseRecord.Data.PIIEntities = entities;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Log the exceptions and/or warnings
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Add the record to the response colletion
                    response.Values.Add(responseRecord);
                }
            }
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(response);
        }
    }
```

And within your Cognitive Search skillset, you add your custom skill definition:

```
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": "Custom PII search custom skill",
      "context": "/document",
      "uri": "https:// <<FUNCTION NAME>> .azurewebsites.net/api/PIIDetectionSkill?code= <KEY> ==",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1000,
      "degreeOfParallelism": null,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "<<PUT YOUR SOURCE NODE HERE>>"
        },
        {
          "name": "languagecode",
          "source": "= null"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "redactedText",
          "targetName": "redactedText"
        }
      ],
      "httpHeaders": {}
    }
```